# Conditionally remove rows from ms access query (SQL)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to remove rows (about 10000) from a report in ms access. I am comparing two sets of two column in a table. When I run the query I would like it to remove the rows where column 1 and 3 match and column 2 and 4 match. I have tried running a left join query and trying with vba code but can't get it to work.

Here is the data

[image]

I have tried using VBA

```
Private Sub Report_Open()
   Dim prism_box As String
   Dim prism_recs As String
   Dim keepdrop_box As String
   Dim keepdrop_recs As String

   prism_box = CStr(Me.[tbl_KeepDrop_remainingpackets_RecId])
   prism_recs = CStr(Me.[tbl_KeepDrop_remainingpackets_RecId])
   keepdrop_box = CStr(Me.[Duplicate Recids_Box#])
   keepdrop_recs = CStr(Me.[Duplicate Recids_RecId])

   If prism_box = keepdrop_box & prism_recs = keepdrop_recs Then

   End If
End Sub
```

I have tried using query too but won't delete them.

I would like the final result to report a table like this...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a report, you are better off creating a query that excludes what you don't want to see.

Pull in whatever fields you need then create two more fields that have `iif([column1] = [column3], True, False)` and `iif([column2] = [column4], True, False` Add into criteria `False` and then point your report's recordsource at that query. (Change the column1-4 into their actual names)